# QGIS Raster reprojection error (gdalwarp: no such file or directory)

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system, gdal

I am working with QGIS 3.4.4 Madeira (OSGeo4W)
I have a Digital Elevation Model/Digital Terrain Model of a watershed with a EPSG:3006 - SWEREF99 TM - CRS (that is actually unsuitable for the DEM cause the DEM-Area is out of the boundaries of that CRS. That file was given to me by someone else, so I don't know why they used this crs) 
I wanted to reproject it to WGS84 UTM33N. I used the QGIS Raster->Projection->Reproject it returns the error ERROR 4: false: No such file or directory

that is the command (i replaced the file path wit ...)

`{ 'DATA_TYPE' : 0, 'EXTRA' : False, 'INPUT' : 'C:/...file.tif', 'MULTITHREADING' : False, 'NODATA' : None, 'OPTIONS' : '', 'OUTPUT' : 'C:/.../file.tif', 'RESAMPLING' : 0, 'SOURCE_CRS' : None, 'TARGET_CRS' : QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:32633'), 'TARGET_EXTENT' : None, 'TARGET_EXTENT_CRS' : None, 'TARGET_RESOLUTION' : None }`

`GDAL command:
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:32633 -r near -of GTiff false C:/Users/Tobias/Documents/Studienprojekt/DGM/Lockwitz_DGM.tif C:/.../file.tif
GDAL command output:
ERROR 4: false: No such file or directory`

The file is there! I tried with the file loaded to QGIS; directly put in the file-path; save as temporary-file; save permanent
Nothing works always this Error, I also tried with another DEM (ASTER-GLOBAL-DEM, and SRTM-DEM) but I always get this error. So is there something I am doing wrong or misunderstand regarding that function? Or has anybody experienced similar issues with that? (Just started using QGIS so excuse if I overlooked something)

Comment: Error seems to come from output `output: ERROR 4: false: No such file or directory`. Does the output directory certainly exist and do you have rights to create new files into it?

Comment: I think the `output` is from the `GDAL command output:` which I would interpret just as the output of the command itself. But anyway QGIS should have access to that file path. I tried different paths and it's always the same. Other functions operate without any problem on that file path, even other gdal-functions work fine.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry for confusion. But I made a trial with my QGIS 3.4.4 and it does not produce that 'EXTRA' : false parameter.

Answer (score 2):

That was a bug in the algorithm, already reported (https://issues.qgis.org/issues/21159) and fixed (https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/9094).

Upgrade to QGIS 3.4.5 (LTR) or 3.6.0 (current).

Answer (score 1):

try it without the

```
false
```

The code tries to use it as the directory

Comment: I can't access the gdal-command line through the QGIS function-window. Is there any way to access the command prompt via QGIS?

I installed QGIS 3.6, calling the reprojection-function there doesn't include the `false` in the command line, and it works. So as you said, the `false` is the problem.

Comment: Extensions---> Python Console